# Custom border - CSS

Tags: css, border

Is there a way to implement this custom border on css?i tried with border-radius but i did not find a solution until now...the black part represents how I wish the border to look like

[image: the black part represents how I wish the border to look like]

My problem is that I want a straight line from the bottom-corner to the rows.

Comment: You are much more likely to get a good answer if you include some basic code for the table/row that people can hack on. http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guaranteed to work in all browsers? Use an image for it. Doing it via CSS, quick and filthy, you can do stuff like this, no idea about browser compatibility

```
.arrow-left {
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid black;
}
.arrow-right {
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 20px solid black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Z2ka/1/

Answer (score 0):

you can use some thing like this:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/5tT62/)

```
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    background: #333;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px 50px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to do this...but my problem is that I want a straight line from the bottom-corner to the rows!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try different approach, which is a background for the beginning and ending of your DIV. That would be triangle saved in gif/png format.

Also if the div has fixed size, it can very well be single image file (also gif/png as it has to be transparent).

This way you make sure all browsers will support your solution which is unlikely with CSS tricks. (I mostly worry about IE 7.0/8.0)